# What is the best way to pass environment variable to TestNG for Automation

Tags: maven, testing, automation, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I would like to pass environment variable for Database connections and many other utilities. Currently, i am passing this variable from POM.xml as a variable which is working fine but created multiple pom.xml for multiple environments. Is there any other standard way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to just leverage JVM arguments for this.

For e.g., you could define something like below in your code wherein you are also defining default values for your JVM arguments:

```
String username = System.getProperty("username","defaultUser");
String password = System.getProperty("password","password");
```

You now pass values for these via command line using `-Dusername=sa -Dpassword=sa`